# Notepad++ : How to stop double click highlighting from grabbing single quotes?

Tags: notepad++

I presume this is also called Word Highlighting, I'm not sure.
I'm using Javascript (a `.js` file) and in Notepad++ (v7.3.3) given these two lines:

```
myFuncA("param");
myFuncB('param');
```

With my Notepad++, if I double click param on the first line it gets `param`. And on the second line it gets `'param'`. While this might be fine for English, I'm writing in Javascript here and I don't like this behavior. Its stops the smart highlighting from working correctly. Unless everything is in double quotes. Which is not always possible or its just a big pain in the ass. I have crafted an example of bad programming as a quick one line example:

```
x.innerHTML = "<span class='foo bar' onclick='this.className=\"bar\"'>foo bar</span>";
```

or

```
x.innerHTML = '<span class="foo bar" onclick="this.className=\'bar\'">foo bar</span>';
```

If I double click `foo` or `bar` it won't smart highlight all of them. Because if you double click and highlight a word next to a `'` it will select the `'` and not find the others, and vice versa.

*(Although, using `\"bar\"` in the second example does work.)*

Is there any way to adjust how it highlights for the double click so that in the two examples above if you click any `foo` or `bar` it will not highlight `'` ?
 (and therefore, smart highlight will highlight them all)

P.s. Also, I am using the Obsidian theme. But, doing a quick change back to default theme does not fix it.

PT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I too ran into this problem.  My solution requires the "NppExec" plugin. Use this command in the NppExec console:

```
sci_sendmsg 2077  0 @"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890-_"
```

You will lose the ability to double-click select words like "can't", but when writing code that is such a rare case.  Also, I believe this affects other word matching functionality.

For a more complete solution:

- Save that code as "StartupScript".
- Go to the NppExec "Advanced Options".
- Set the "Execute this script when Notepad++ starts" drop-down to "StartupScript".

Pro Tip: You can add other characters to the string to be included in matching, such as `$` to select a whole variable name in PHP.

Edit: I just realized that this script is only run on the current document, so double clicking in a different document will have unwanted behavior. When I figure out a way to apply it to all the documents I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thanks, this is neat. Also, my NP++ does not select `-` so some HTML element attributes do not select. (For sites that have element attributes like `message-id`). Anyhow, having to run a script at startup is not the solution I was hoping for. I guess there is not a simple setting, possibly global, somewhere.

Comment: @PimpTrizkit At least for **adding** delimiters go to Settings > Preferences >  Delimiter, then toggle "Add your character as part of word" then you can add w/e characters you want to be part of a word.  Unfortunately this doesn't remove characters...

Comment: Oh, I guess that could solve my issue. I can just add the `'`. I'm still questioning the `-` tho. Because I would like `border-width` to select but not the x-y in this example : `"style='border-width:"+(x-y)+";'"`

Comment: Maybe it stores the data for that setting somewhere like the registry or an `.ini` file? maybe deleting can be done that way

Comment: The strangest thing happened. I rebooted my computer. And now notepad++ is working fine again. It does not highlight `'` on double click. And I have not yet done your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I just tested this and it's working fine in Notepad++. What is the file extension of the file you are using? What version of Notepad++ (I'm using 7.2.2)

Comment: EDITED OP - v7.3.3 - Always the newest. Its a `.js` file. Notepad++ has recognized it as such and using the associated style configuration. I did change the style theme to Obsidian....

Comment: @PimpTrizkit Have you tried to copy and paste the text in the original post into a blank document? That's how I'm testing it even with Obsidian theme it works fine.

Comment: Yup, just tried. No change. I guess something is wrong with my configuration, but I don't know where to look to change the setting. Hence, the question.